# How to generate a specific SQL query for Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: support, data-explorer

First, let me say I wasn't sure if I should post here or in the database stack, so I apologize in advance. 
My SQL is not strong, so any help would be much appreciated.
I am trying to come up with a query that will return the `OwnerUserId, OwnerDisplayName` pairs of posts that are the respective accepted answers to `PostTypeId = 1` posts whose `Body LIKE '%Differential Geometry%' or Title LIKE '%Differential Geometry%`.

In other words, I am trying to return a list of users with the best answers to questions about "Differential Geometry."

Here is what I have, and it seems to work, but probably not efficiently at all.

```
SELECT TOP 100
b.OwnerUserId [User Link], a.Id [Post Link]
FROM Posts as a, Posts as b
WHERE
(a.AcceptedAnswerId is not null) and 
(b.id = a.AcceptedAnswerId) and 
(a.PostTypeId = 1 and b.PostTypeId = 2) and
(a.Body LIKE '%Probability%' or a.Title LIKE '%Probability%')
```

Comment: You mean, instead of the user ids, you want to see the usernames?

Comment: I want to see both. I am starting to thing usernames are protected from queries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand correctly your explanation and the code,
you're looking for questions with "Differential Topology" in the title or body that have an accepted answer, and see the usernames of the authors of those questions.

In your query you selected `OwnerUserId`, which is the user id, not the username. Although there is a `OwnerDisplayName` field, that seems to be empty. You could get the usernames by joining with the `Users` table on `Users.Id`. An interesting alternative that's a bit different but perhaps better is to select `OwnerUserId AS [User Link]`. By using the `AS [User Link]`, the column becomes a link to the user profile, with the username as the label instead of the id.

Another thing, your query joining two tables is inefficient.
To find questions with an accepted answer,
instead of a join you could use a `AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL` condition.

Consider [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/611889/764716/questions-with-accepted-answer-matching-differential-topology) more efficient, simpler alternative:

```
SELECT TOP 100
  q.Id [Post Link],
  q.OwnerUserId [User Link],
  q.Title,
  q.Body
FROM Posts q
WHERE
  q.PostTypeId = 1
  AND q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL
  AND (q.Body LIKE '%Differential Topology%' OR q.Title LIKE '%Differential Topology%')
```

The above query does what your original query did.
As you wrote in your comment,
what you're really looking for is the user ids and usernames of accepted answers.
For that, indeed you need to join question posts and answer posts.
Here's [another query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/611916/764743/accepted-answers-matching-phrase) for that,
parameterized for easier use:

```
DECLARE @phrase AS NVARCHAR(60) = ##Text:string? ##;

SELECT TOP ##Limit:int?100##
  a.OwnerUserId,
  a.OwnerUserId [User Link],
  q.Id [Post Link]
FROM Posts q
JOIN Posts a
  ON q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL
  AND q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE
  q.Body LIKE '%' + @phrase + '%'
  OR q.Title LIKE '%' + @phrase + '%'
ORDER BY a.Score DESC
```

Lastly (and to answer your final(?) comment),
instead of doing full text search on post titles and bodies,
it will be more efficient to search by tags.
Here's [one more query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/611916/764767/accepted-answers-matching-phrase) with an optional tag parameter:

```
DECLARE @tag AS NVARCHAR(60) = ##Tag:string? ##;
DECLARE @phrase AS NVARCHAR(60) = ##Text:string? ##;

SELECT TOP ##Limit:int?100##
  a.OwnerUserId,
  a.OwnerUserId [User Link],
  q.Id [Post Link]
FROM Posts q
JOIN Posts a
  ON q.AcceptedAnswerId IS NOT NULL
  AND q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE
  (@tag = '' OR LOWER(q.Tags) LIKE '%<' + LOWER(RTRIM(LTRIM(@tag))) + '>%')
  AND (@phrase = '' OR q.Body LIKE '%' + @phrase + '%' OR q.Title LIKE '%' + @phrase + '%')
ORDER BY a.Score DESC
```

Comment: @Geano I added one more extension to respond to for your final (now deleted?) comment